# Redirect to a file in unix

Tags: python, unix

I need to generate a python script from unix script.

I know `echo "your text" > your_python_filename` can do it but I need to take care of the indentations and quotes / special charecters. Below is my contents.

```
import getopt
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
    for arg in sys.argv:
        print arg
print "End"
```

I wish to feed these contents to the unix shell script say generate.sh and upon running the generate.sh should generate my python output.py with the correct indentations and special charecter and quotes.

Comment: What is this script supposed to do?  It's pretty unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Maybe give some sample input and what you would like to have output?

Comment: \t is the escapesequence for a tab, although spaces are preferred as far as i know.

Comment: i think it is clear, OP is tring to generate python code using a shell script. in python blocks are representet by indentication of code lines. he also needs to take care of string literals and so on.

Comment: It's not clear what problems do you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
#cat << EOF > output.py
>import getopt
>for arg in sys.argv:
>    print arg
>    for arg in sys.argv:
>        print arg
>print "End"
>EOF
```

Now you can do:
cat output.py and you see your code indented.

hope it helps

Comment: If need to do it in a Bash script, check the 19.8 Example of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide. [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: This helped !! If need to do it in a Bash script, check the 19.8 Example of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide. link – ACortes      Where do i click to consider this been answered ?

Comment: Great, a pleasure to have helped. To close the question check the ask FAQ of [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: In example 19.8 how can I pass the variable so that its value is what is populated in the generated output file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "HEREDOC" and feed the source code directly to the Python interpreter.

```
python - arg1 anotherarg <<EOP
> import getopt,sys
> for arg in sys.argv:
>     print arg
>     for arg in sys.argv:
>         print arg
> print "End"
> EOP
```

Make sure the first argument is `-` to read the source from stdin.